# How can I save matrix order via plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix

I am able to add/delete matrix blocks from within my plugin without any problems. I would like to give the user the ability to drag & drop any field just as you can within the CP.

I can use [jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to create the functionality no problem. I am curious what/how to call within Craft that manages order so that it is saved.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix blocks are saved in the order they appear in the POST data when saving the "owner" element (the entry, or whatever). So just adding jQuery Sortable to your front-end form will be enough.

Comment: Ah - perfect thank you, Brandon! I wasn't sure if there was an additional call I needed to make.

Answer (score 0):

You'd re-save the element with the field set to the re-ordered array of IDs representing the Matrix blocks.

You don't have to save the blocks themselves, just the element.

Comment: Thank you, Carlcs - I have everything set up - I should have just given it a shot in the first place :)